# whats up with QLayout->setParent

Tags: qt

When I try to change the location of a layout with setParent the result is non-functional or odd.

the following works:

```
ui.txDiag_1->setParent(ui.tab_2);
movingHlayout = new QVBoxLayout(ui.tab_2);
movingHlayout->setSpacing(3);
movingHlayout->setMargin(3);
movingHlayout->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("movingHlayout"));
movingHlayout->addWidget(ui.txDiag_1);
```

but this doesnt(movingHlayout has been constructed before hand):

```
ui.txDiag_1->setParent(ui.tab_2);
movingHlayout->setParent(ui.tab_2);
movingHlayout->setSpacing(3);
movingHlayout->setMargin(3);
movingHlayout->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("movingHlayout"));
movingHlayout->addWidget(ui.txDiag_1);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You possibly have to call setLayout() on the widget you are setting the layout up in.

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#setLayout

As you can see from the docs, the ownership of the layout will automatically be set to the target widget.

Answer (score 0):

To complete the other answer, here is the reason why `setParent` does not work as you expect:

`setParent` is not in `QLayout` implementation, but in `QObject` only. So using it will only change the pointer ownership and deletion, not the widget layout mechanism.